# Mustache: only show if key has non-false value

Tags: mustache, handlebars.js

In a Mustache template, how can I show a block containing a value only when said value is a non-false value?

I need to be able to show or not show an entire block, not just the value.

For example, in Handlebars:

```
{{#if name}}
    Hi {{name}}!
{{/if}}
```

[But in Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html), "when the value is non-false but not a list, it will be used ***as the context*** (emphasis mine) for a single rendering of the block.":

```
{{#person?}}
    Hi {{name}}!
{{/person?}}
```

But I don't want to set context, I want to check the key and have direct access to it's value inside the block.

I made the following unsuccessful attempts:

```
{{#name}}
    Hi {{name}}!
{{/name}}

{{#name}}
    Hi {{this}}!
{{/name}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{#name}}Hi {{name}}!{{/name}}` should just work fine, since a string has to prevent the section rendering if it is missing or empty. The fact that the string enters the context stack should not bother you: the inner `{{name}}` tag will still fetch and render the string.

If `{{#name}}Hi {{name}}!{{/name}}` does not behave as expected, there are two possible explanations: your input data is not the one you think it is, or you are using a Mustache implementation that does not follow the specification (and it is an issue).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is a custom Mustache implementation. I tested this successfully with a stock version of Mustache.